# I need my URL as page=2 not as page/2 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination, permalinks

I have a migration site in which I need URL structure for pagination is page=2 but in WordPress custom post permalink it changed to page/2.

How can I change it to page=2 in URL? 
Reguired URL: http://site-url.com/page/?page=2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Happy new year dots

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/change-permalink-structure-for-pagination-only) ?